# Handling multiple forms on a single page

Tags: laravel-5

I have a page with a select option

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <select class="selection" name="selection">
        <option value="ab">Form One</option>
        <option value="ad">Form Two</option>
        <option value="nq">Form Three</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

For my JQuery, I just listen for the change

```
$(".selection").on("change", function(e){
    if($(this).val() == "ad"){
        $("#content").append(data);
    }
});
```

Now where this blade template lives (resources/views/customer), I have created a forms folder.  In this folder are form1.blade.php and two more templates for the other forms.

How would I go about added the form template into the div with the id content?

Or is there a better way of handling multiple forms for a single page?

Comment: Can each form (form1, form2, form3) be included multiple times on one page? For example, can I add form1 3x times, and form2 x5 times? Or just once?

Comment: each form can be added just once

Comment: Why don't you just include them in the base blade next to the select?

Comment: I was going to do that, but thought it would be a bit messy having them all in the one file

Comment: You can just use `@include('blade/path/form1')` if you want

Answer (score 6):

Suppose, you have two forms like this:

**View** :

```
<form action="/url" method="post">
    <input name="some_field" value="1">
    <button type="submit" name="form1">Submit 1</button>
</form>
<form action="/url" method="post">
    <input name="some_field" value="1">
    <button type="submit" name="form2">Submit 2</button>
</form>
```

Now in **Controller** :

```
if ($request->has('form1')) {
    //handle form1
}

if ($request->has('form2')) {
    //handle form2
}
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/two-form-on-one-page-both-submit

Comment: Yeah this is eazy and work well! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assign values to submit and check to see if `$request->has()` the value. Then use logic inside the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an id to the form you wanna submit.

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click","#formPass",function() {
        $(this).parents("form").submit();
    });
</script>
```