# Multiple forms on one page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application I have a sign up process in which users must select a category they fall under, each category is in it's own form.

In each of these forms there are a set of checkboxes and users must tick at least one, otherwise validation should fail, I've been doing some reading and found two great, similar questions:

[Handling multiple forms on a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789076/handling-multiple-forms-on-a-single-page)

[Laravel request validation with multiple forms on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991026/laravel-request-validation-with-multiple-forms-on-the-same-page)

At the moment I'm feeding all 3 forms to the same method:

```
/**
 * Store a user's selected investor type and progress onto next stage
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return void
 */
public function storeInvestorType(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    $user->investor_type = $request->get('investor_type');

    $user->declaration_date = Carbon::now();

    $user->save();

    Log::info("{$user->log_reference} has declared that they are a '{$user->investor_type}' investor.");

    return redirect()->route('user.member-type');
}
```

Which literally just updates a column in a database.

Would it be cleaner to have 3 separate methods or just to name each form?

**An update**

I have added a `name="something"` to each submit button so that I can do something like this in the controller:

```
/**
 * Store a user's selected investor type and progress onto next stage
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return void
 */
public function storeInvestorType(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    if ($request->has('high_net_worth')){
        if(!$request->has('high_net_worth_criteria')){
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Please tick at least one criteria that specifies you are a High Net Worth investor');
        } else{
            $investor_type = "High Net Worth";
        }
    } elseif ($request->has('self_certified_sophisticated')) {
        if (!$request->has('self_certified_sophisticated_criteria')) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Please tick at least one criteria that specifies you are a Self-Certified Sophisticated investor');
        } else {
            $investor_type = "Self-Certified Sophisticated";
        }
    } elseif ($request->has('other')) {
        $investor_type = "Other";
    }

    $user->investor_type = $investor_type;

    $user->declaration_date = Carbon::now();

    $user->save();

    Log::info("{$user->log_reference} has declared that they are a '{$user->investor_type}' investor.");

    return redirect()->route('user.member-type');
}
```

Comment: Why do you have three forms to begin with? I would imagine this as being a case of selecting one of three buttons and returning the variable to the controller, because no other form data is used? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Two of the forms have criteria in the way of checkboxes